# Lightning passing the id and changing the component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How do I pass a id, change the component to a different view and load results related to that id in the init function.
cmp:

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
            <a  id="{!account.Id}" onclick = "{!c.getAccounts}"> 

                {!account.Name}
                </a>
              <br/>
            </aura:iteration>
```

controller:

```
getAccounts: function(component,event,helper){
   var selectedItem = event.target.id;;
      var accountEvent = $A.get("e.c:accountId");
      accountEvent .setParams({ "accountId" : selectedItem });
      accountEvent .fire();     
}
```

Comment: @MohithShrivastava updated my question, now when I handle my event in the other component how to change component or navigate to different component and get list of all related object content on the account that user clicks

Answer (score 3):

Finally winter 17 gave this much needed feature to navigate between components in lightning .Note the feature is in BETA you have to be in Winter 17 org to test this .

Here is a sample code

```
navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:myComponent",
        componentAttributes: {
            contactName : component.get("v.contact.Name")
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

where **componentDef** is the  component to navigate to, for example, c:myComponent

**componentAttributes** is the attributes that you pass from one component to the other .

Before the only way to use this was use $A.createComponent and this blog highlights how to write custom [navigate](https://force-base.com/2016/01/04/how-to-navigate-from-one-component-to-another-in-lightning/) code .